# What is the correct value of $\theta$ for this problem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**A kite $100 \mathrm{ft}$ above the ground moves horizontally at a speed $4 \mathrm{ft}/\mathrm{s}$. At what rate is the angle between the string and the horizontal decreasing when $300 \mathrm{ft}$ of string has been let out?**

In terms of what I've solved.

$z = 300^2, x = 200\sqrt{2}, y = 100^2$

The value of $x$ was obtained from the equation $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$

In order to obtain the relationship between the angle, I used the trig value of $\tan$.

My final equation is $(100/200 \sqrt{2})(4\cos^2(θ))$.

I do not understand what should be the value of $\theta$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $z^2$.
We are given y to be constant and equal to 100, so $x^2$ + $100^2$ = $z^2$. Since the string is being continuously released, we can think of the length of string released, $z$, as a function of time. Likewise, the horizontal displacement, $x$, can also be thought of as a function of time. We are given that the kite is moving horizontally at a constant speed of 4ft/s, which translates to $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = 4. We can define the angle of interest $\theta$ to be arctan($\frac{100}{x}$). We can use implicit differentiation to differentiate both sides of the equation $\theta$ = arctan($\frac{100}{x}$) to obtain: 
$\theta$ = arctan($\frac{100}{x}$) $\implies$ $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ = -$\frac{100}{x^2+100^2}$ $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = -$\frac{400}{x^2+100^2}$ (using $\frac{dx}{dt} = 4$) 
Now, going back to the original equation $x^2$+$100^2$=$z^2$, and the fact that 300ft of string has been released (z=300), we can see that $x^2$ = $300^2$ - $100^2$. We can substitute in to find that; 
$\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ = -$\frac{400}{x^2+100^2}$ = -$\frac{400}{300^2}$ = -$\frac{1}{225}$ 
So the angle is decreasing at a rate of $\frac{1}{225}$rad/s